# How to use angle brackets in the command line arguments?

Tags: tcl

How to use an angle brackets in command line arguments?

Suppose the input is:    `filename -w <input.txt>`

Here `input.txt` is a second command line argument, and it is an input file to a program here input.txt must be enclosed by angle brackets( `<input.txt>` ) . But if I use angular brackets i m getting error. error is :

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: -c: line 0: `demo -w '
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do exactly... Could you perhaps elaborate? Also, what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. However, it seems to me a shell problem, not a Tcl one.

I suppose your `filename` is the name of a Tcl executable script and you want to give it `input.txt` as parameter.

But the angle brackets have special meaning to the shell. `sh` interprets the `<` as standard input redirecting, so it reads the content of `input.txt` and passes it to `filename` through the standard input channel.

Then, `sh` interprets the `>` as standard output redirecting, but after that there is no name to redirect the output to, so it gives you the error you see, because after `>` you pressed the `Return` key.

So, are you sure your script needs the filename surrounded by angle brackets? If so, escape the brackets, like

```
filename -w \<input.txt\>
```

Otherwise, try to *completely* remove the brackets and use

```
filename -w input.txt
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: A side note: Tcl's `exec` _cannot_ directly feed `<anything>` as an argument to any program. It's a known misfeature (because `exec` tries to look like `/bin/sh` syntax without actually supporting it) that we're looking at fixing.