# how to use angle brackets within the command line argument in TCL?

Tags: tcl

How to use an angle brackets in command line arguments?

Suppose the input is:    `filename -w <input.txt>`

Here `input.txt` is a second command line argument, and it is an input file to a program here input.txt must be enclosed by angle brackets(  ) . But if I use angular brackets i m getting error. error is :

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: -c: line 0: `demo -w '
```

Comment: @Jerry _Possible_ duplicate? =)

Comment: @potrzebie That's the default comment of SO when you vote to close as duplicate! I left it as such xD

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice? You could have added any additional information to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299614/how-to-use-angle-brackets-in-the-command-line-arguments